# iPhone app alters view on willChangeStatusBarFrame and suspend

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, uinavigationbar

In my application, I have a UINavigationController with a UINavigationBar that I created programmatically. The UINavigationBar has custom positioning within the view, but whenever will/didChangeStatusBarFrame is called (when you enable the in-call status bar), or the app suspends and resumes, the navBar automagically moves back to the top of the screen.

I was able to override this behavior somewhat by keeping my navBar in place at the bottom, but now it creates a SECOND navBar which it moves to the top.

Why is this happening, and how do I prevent it from happening?  This is a new issue with iOS 4 - the app ran fine in both 2.x and 3.x.

Also, before a discussion about Human Interface Guidelines is started, please note that I'm aware Apple doesn't want UINavigationBars at the bottom.  However, this is a custom app that will be used by me and me alone, and I require that the bar be at the bottom.  Additionally, this issue is driving me nuts and I want to know the answer no matter where my navBar lies...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whelp, this is a bit of a hack, but it works.
To keep the navBar at the bottom when the in-call status is displayed:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame {
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame {
    [navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    CGSize s2 = navBar.bounds.size;
    [navBar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [navigationController.view bounds].size.height-s2.height, s2.width, s2.height)];

}
```

And since multitasking with this app is not only unnecessary but also unwanted, I disabled it by adding the following to the plist:

```
Application does not run in background
```

This still doesn't really answer my question about why the navBar was jumping to the top, and it's a hackish fix, but it will have to work for now.